# How to mock internal interface that is provided by Koin?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, koin

Currently trying to write a unit test for my view model in the Android app.
The problem is in one of my functions there is a call of the KoinComponent function.
This component contents val that is set by koin, looks something like this:

```
object Component: KoinComponent {
private val api = get<ApiInterface>()
fun doSomething() {}
}
```

In my viewModel i have a fun that executes doSomething().
Due to it requiring Koin to start test fails.
I know that I can mock this but the problem is that KoinComponent is public and ApiInterface is not. If I make the interface public - the mock works fine, otherwise I can't do anything.
So the question is: is there any way to make this interface visible for tests or maybe make KoinComponent mock it by itself?
Thanks!

Tried to make interface public to mock everything function needs.